# Rails 3.1.1 assets precompile - rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, precompile, asset-pipeline

**EDIT: Anybody else has any suggestions? I'm totally stumped!!!**

I have an app in which all the assets compile just fine but in this second app, when I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
```

I get the following message: **undefined method `directory?' for nil:NilClass**

Please help. When I look under the public/assets directory I see that the image files have been precompiled but none of the js or css files.

Below is the full terminal output:

```
=> RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
undefined method `directory?' for nil:NilClass
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:122:in `block in each_entry'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:118:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:118:in `each_entry'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:137:in `block in each_file'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:136:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:136:in `each_file'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:149:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:52:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p2...]
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `sh'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:78:in `ruby'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `ruby'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/swamiatma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@lasource/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: i guess that you did something wrong in your configuration. mistyping a path or something like that. i would do a bundle open sprockets and add some debugging output to see what path it is that causes the error.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to go about doing this debugging within sprockets?

Comment: you do a `bundle open sprockets` and then use your favorite texteditor to add puts statements, debugging lines, or pry or whatever tool fits your needs.

Comment: You must be very good phoet. I'm willing but I'm not sure where to put the statements. There are so many files and so much code in sprockets that I can't figure out where to put the puts statements and what to output exactly. Can you give me a little more hand holding?

Comment: Never mind, I realized that the trace was pointing to base.rb line 122. duh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Phoet's suggestions I added a puts statement in the base file of sprockets and that gave me the culprit file. It was a ckeditor js file. I have moved ckeditor outside the pipeline in the public directory but this file was somehow called for inclusion. I still don't know why. But I put a dummy ckeditor.js file in the assets/javascripts directory and that was enough to fix my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to phoet: I just surrounded those lines with an `begin..rescue` block at `.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb`. The error was caused by an invalid symlink (only in production env with rails 3.1.1 sprockets 2.0.2, additionally rack 1.3.4 caused an `constant WFKV_` warning but rack 1.3.3 doesn't)

```
120  paths << path
121  begin
122    if stat(path).directory?
123      each_entry(path) do |subpath|
124        paths << subpath
125      end
126    end
127  rescue
128    puts "error with directory #{path}"
129  end
```

Now the error is gone and `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace` comes to an end, but needs an eternity at the last two steps `** Execute assets:precompile:primary` right after tmp:cache:clear ... we will see ;)

Comment: The key phrase here is "broken symbolic link".